# LLVM: add target independent instruction in MachineFunctionPass?

Tags: llvm

Is there a target independent move instruction that I can pass to llvm::BuildMI in MachineInstrBuilder? Inside a machine function pass I would like to add a machine instruction to the existing basic block. Is that possible?